# Highcharts: Multiple vertical charts

Tags: graph, charts, highcharts

I'm wondering if it's possible to have one Highcharts-generated graphic with 1 x-axis, and two separate y-axis - one stacked vertically on top of the other.

I've currently got a spline chart on top (as in z axis) of a stacked column chart, with the appropriate y-axis moved to the opposite side, just like this demo: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes. What I would like to do is move the spline chart and it's y-axis vertically above the column chart like so:

```
+--------------------------+
| +----------------------+ |
| |  Spline chart here   | |
| +----------------------+ |
| +----------------------+ |
| |  Column chart here   | |
| |  X-axis for both     | |
| +----------------------+ |
+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take look at this example http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume